# Fibonacci series in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

```js
function fib(n) {

  const result = [0, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    const a = (i - 1);
    const b = (i - 2);
    result.push(a + b);
  }
  return result[n];

}

console.log(fib(8));
```

The output of the code above is `13`. I don't understand the for loop part. In very first iteration `i = 2`, but after second iteration `i = 3` so `a = 2` and `b = 1` and third iteration `i = 4` so `a = 3`, `b = 2`, and so on... If it's going on final sequence will be :
`[0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]`, which is incorrect. The correct sequence will be `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`

Comment: What do you want to return? `result` or `result[n]`?

Comment: You are not using the previous two numbers to generate the new number.

Comment: Please remember that you can and should accept an answer if the problem is solved - Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

> You were not using the previous two numbers that are already in the array to > generate the new fibonacci number to be inserted into the array.

https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html

Here I have used the sum of `result[i-2]` and `result[i-1]` to generate the new fibonacci number and pushed it into the array.

Also to generate `n` number of terms you need the condition to be `i < n` and not `i <= n`.

```js
function fib(n) {

  const result = [0, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    result.push(result[i-2] + result[i-1]);
  }
  return result; // or result[n-1] if you want to get the nth term

}

console.log(fib(8));
```

Return `result[n-1]` if you want to get the nth term.

Answer (score 5):

My solution for Fibonacci series:

```
 const fibonacci = n =>
      [...Array(n)].reduce(
        (acc, val, i) => acc.concat(i > 1 ? acc[i - 1] + acc[i - 2] : i),
        []
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

This function is incorrect. It cat be checked by just adding the `console.log` call just before the function return:

```js
function fib(n) {

  const result = [0, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    const a = (i - 1);
    const b = (i - 2);
    result.push(a + b);
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result[n];

}

console.log(fib(7));
```

As you can see, the sequence is wrong and (for `n = 7`) the return value is too.

The possible change would be as following:

```js
function fib(n) {

  const result = [0, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    const a = result[i - 1];
    const b = result[i - 2];
    result.push(a + b);
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result[n];

}

console.log(fib(8));
```

This is the "classical" Fibonacci numbers; if you really want to use the first number of `0`, not `1`, then you should `return result[n-1]`, since array indexes start from zero.

Answer (score 2):

One approach you could take for fibonacci sequence is recursion:

```js
var fibonacci = {
  getSequenceNumber: function(n) {
    //base case to end recursive calls
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
      return this.cache[n];
    }

    //if we already have it in the cache, use it
    if (this.cache[n]) {
      return this.cache[n];
    }
    //calculate and store in the cache for future use
    else {
      //since the function calls itself it's called 'recursive'
      this.cache[n] = this.getSequenceNumber(n - 2) + this.getSequenceNumber(n - 1);
    }

    return this.cache[n];
  },

  cache: {
    0: 0,
    1: 1
  }
}
//find the 7th number in the fibbonacci function
console.log(fibonacci.getSequenceNumber(7));

//see all the values we cached (preventing extra work)
console.log(fibonacci.cache);

//if you want to output the entire sequence as an array:
console.log(Object.values(fibonacci.cache));
```

The code above is also an example of a [dynamic programming](https://medium.com/@hernangarchtrom/simple-dynamic-programming-example-91a0074f55fc) approach. You can see that I am storing each result in a `cache` object the first time it is calculated by the `getSequenceNumber` method. This way, the second time that `getSequenceNumber` is asked to find a given input, it doesn't have to do any actual work - just grab the value from `cache` and return it! This is an optimization technique that can be applied to functions like this where you may have to find the value of a particular input multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is adding the iterator index (i), whereas what you need to do is add the element in the `result` at that index.

```js
function fib(n) {

  const result = [0, 1];

  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    const a = result[(i - 1)];
    const b = result[(i - 2)];
    result.push(a + b);
  }
  console.log("Result Array: " + result);
  return result[n];

}

console.log("Fibonacci Series element at 8: " + fib(8));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fib = n => {
  const array = Array(n);
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i > 1) {
      array[i] = array[i - 1] + array[i - 2];
    } else {
      array[i] = 1;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(fib(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the logic:

1. Variables `a` and `b` currently refer to `i - 1` and `i - 2`. Instead they should refer to the elements of `result` array, i.e. `result[i - 1]` and `result[i - 2]`.
2. If you need 8th element of the array, you need to call `result[7]`. So the returned value should be `result[n - 1]` instead of `result[n]`.

```js
function fib(n) {

  const result = [0, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    const a = result[i - 1];
    const b = result[i - 2];
    result.push(a + b);
  }
  
  console.log(result);
  return result[n - 1];
}

console.log(fib(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution for Fibonacci series:

```
function fib(n){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <n; i++ ){
        if(i == 0 || i == 1){
            arr.push(i);
        } else {
            var a = arr[i - 1];
            var b = arr[i - 2];
            arr.push(a + b);
        }
    }
    return arr
}
console.log(fib(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly one of those "more than one way to clean chicken" type situations, this JavaScript method below works for me.

```
function fibCalc(n) {
    var myArr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i < 2) {
            myArr.push(i);
        } else {
            myArr.push(myArr[i-2] + myArr[i-1]);
        }
    } 

    return myArr;
}

fibCalc(8);
```

When called as above, this produces [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
It allows me to have a sequence of fib numbers based on n.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fib(n) {
    const result = [0];

    if (n > 1) {
        result.push(1);

        for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            const a = result[result.length - 1]
            const b = result[result.length - 2];
            result.push(a + b);
        }

    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this solution to get the n index fibonacci value.

```
function findFac(n){
if (n===1) 
  {
   return [0, 1];
  } 
  else 
  {
    var s = findFac(n - 1);
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    return s;
  }
}

function findFac0(n){
var vv1 = findFac(n);
return vv1[n-1];
}


console.log(findFac0(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have it, with few argument check, without using exception handling

```
function fibonacci(limit){
    if(typeof limit != "number"){return "Please enter a natural number";}

    if(limit <=0){
        return "limit should be at least 1";
    }
    else if(limit == 1){
        return [0];
    }
    else{
        var series = [0, 1];
        for(var num=1; num<=limit-2; num++){
            series.push(series[series.length-1]+series[series.length-2]);
        }
        return series;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution.

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return [0];
    }
    if ( n == 1) {
        return [0, 1];
    } else {
        let fibo = fibonacci(n-1);
        let nextElement = fibo [n-1] + fibo [n-2];
        fibo.push(nextElement);
        return fibo;
    }
}
console.log(fibonacci(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fibonacciGenerator (n) {
 var output = [];
  if(n===1){
    output=[0];
  }else if(n===2){
    output=[0,1];    
  }else{
    output=[0,1];
    for(var i=2; i<n; i++){
      output.push(output[output.length-2] + output[output.length-1]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
output = fibonacciGenerator();
console.log(output);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer could do with some amount of explanation, especially to stand out from the other 13 answers

Answer (score 0):

```
function fibonacci(end) {
    if (isNaN(end) === false && typeof (end) === "number") {
        var one = 0, res, two = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
            res = one + two;
            one = two;
            two = res;
            console.log(res);
        }
    } else {
        console.error("One of the parameters is not correct!")
    }
}

fibonacci(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var input = parseInt(prompt(""));
     var a =0;
     var b=1;
     var x;
     for(i=0;i<=input;i++){
        document.write(a+"<br>")
        x = a+b;
        a =b;
        b= x;
     }
```

Comment: I think this one is easier for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use recursion neither array in memory to compute Fibonacci(n) you can do like this

```
function fibonacci(n) { 
    return Math.round((Math.pow((1 + Math.sqrt(5))/2,n) - (Math.pow(2/(1 + Math.sqrt(5)),n) * (Math.cos(n*Math.PI))))/Math.sqrt(5)); 
}
```

proof: [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%281%2F2%20%281%20%2B%20sqrt%285%29%29%29%5En%20-%20%282%2F%281%20%2B%20sqrt%285%29%29%29%5En%20cos%28n*pi%29%29%2Fsqrt%285%29%20%3D%20fibonacci%28n%29) [closed form of Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence)

if you want then to compute bigger fibonacci(n), because of [limitation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) of integer type in javascript, you have to use a library like [Math.js](https://mathjs.org/) to handle cosine and round and sqrt for BigInt (aka BigNumbers in Math.js)
if not you have to use BigInteger type, for pow you can use ** but for sqrt, round and cos, you have to create your own methods..